# JBoss AS7 fails to deploy Postgresql JDBC 4 driver

Tags: jdbc, jboss7.x, postgresql-9.1

I installed the Postgresql JDBC driver in JBoss AS7 using the deployment method by putting postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc4.jar into thee standalone/deployments/ directory.  When I start AS7 with standalone.sh I get the error below. Note that it calls out "org_postgresql" which makes me think it is a bad configuration file somewhere. I've done a search in all files in my project and in the AS7 installation, but none of them have "org_post" in them.

I get the same error with postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar.

Has anyone else been able to use the deployment method with Postgresql JDBC driver?

```
22:55:31,259 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
service jboss.jdbc-driver.org_postgresql (missing) dependents: [service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/kfv6DS_auth]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment method is broken.  Installing the driver as a core module solves this problem.

Comment: What version of AS 7? I've tested deploying with the maven plugin and it works just fine.

Comment: Version 7.1.1.  I didn't use the maven plugin.  I just did the manual deploy method per the documentation.

Comment: It should work. You could try to deploy it via CLI too. `$JBOSS_HOME/jboss-cli.sh --connect "deploy path_to_postgres_jar"`